# How do I change the width of the header border of antd modal

Tags: css, antd

Modal:
[image]

Need the change the border width to half of the modal or any custom px.

The **antd-modal-header** class has a **.border-bottom** but changing the width is changing the height or making the border look bold but not the size.

Code :

```
  <Modal title="Add Name">
    <p>Some contents...</p>
  </Modal>
```

You can tap into the the below class to access the border.

```
.ant-modal .ant-modal-content .ant-modal-header{
    border-bottom: 2px solid #e9e9e9;//changing in 2px to 1px is reducing the height
}
```

CodeSandbox link :
https://codesandbox.io/s/antd-modal-border-stackoverflow-kwdmb?file=/index.css

Comment: please put an example code over here so others can understand that what you want to make.

Comment: @KuldipKoradia Added a sample code

Comment: please check the answer below I think this will works fine for you.
@Sai Krishnadas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please apply this CSS properties to achieve what you want to do.

```
.ant-modal-header {
    border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
    position: relative;
}
.ant-modal-header:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: #e9e9e9;
    width: 50%;
    height: 2px;
}
```

I have tried this to a demo modal on this website https://ant.design/components/modal/

here us the Screen Shot for what you wants to achieve
[image]

I have also tried it to your CodeSandbox Code: here is the Screen Shot of that.
[image]